# How do you manually mock one of your own files in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to mock an object (which I created) in Jest so I can provide default behaviour within the react component (so the real implementation isn't used)

This is my react component ChatApp (it's very straight forward)

```
'use strict';
var React, ChatApp, ChatPanel, i18n;

React = require('react');
ChatPanel = require('./chat_panel');
i18n = require('../support/i18n');

ChatApp = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="chat-app">
        <h1>{i18n.t("app.title")}</h1>
        <ChatPanel />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = ChatApp;
```

So I have a custom I18n dependency that does translations (I18n is something I've written that is a wrapper for node-polyglot).

So I want to do a basic test to see if the H1 has the correct word in it, but I don't want to set jest.dontMock() on my I18n object, because I don't want it to use the real object in the ChatApp test.

So following the basic instructions on the jest website, I created a **mocks** folder and created a mock file for i18n, which generates a mock from the original object and then overrides the t method and adds a method to allow me to set the return string for t.

This is the mock object

```
'use strict';
var i18nMock, _returnString;

i18nMock = jest.genMockFromModule('../scripts/support/i18n');

_returnString = "";

function __setReturnString(string) {
  _returnString = string;
}

function t(key, options = null) {
  return _returnString;
}

i18nMock.t.mockImplementation(t);
i18nMock.__setReturnString = __setReturnString;

module.exports = i18nMock;
```

Now in my ChatApp test I require the mock in a before each, like so:

```
'use strict';
var React, ChatApp, TestUtils, path;

path = '../../../scripts/components/';
jest.dontMock( path + 'chat_app');

React = require('react/addons');
ChatApp = require( path + 'chat_app');
TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('ChatApp', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    require('i18n').__setReturnString('Chat App');
  });

  var ChatAppElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ChatApp />);

  it('renders a title on the page', () => {
    var title = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(ChatAppElement, 'h1');
    expect(title.tagName).toEqual('H1');
    expect(title.props.children).toEqual('Chat App');
  });
});
```

If i console.log the i18n object within the test then I get the correct mocked object, the __setReturnString also gets triggered (as if I console.log in that message I see the log).

However, if I console.log the i18n object within the actual React component then it gets a Jest mock but it doesn't get my Jest mock, so the t method is an empty method that doesn't do anything, meaning the test fails.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

I've had trouble getting the `__mocks__` folder working as well. The way I got around it is by using the `jest.setMock();` method.

In your case, you would `jest.setMock('../../../scripts/i18n/', require('../__mocks__/i18n');`

Obviously, I am not certain of the location of your mock and the location of the real library you're using, but the first parameter should use the path where your real module is stored and the second should use the path where your mock is stored.

This should force your module and all modules that yours require (including React) to use your manually mocked i18n module.

Answer (score 1):

Jest does automatic mocking. Just `i18n = require('../support/i18n')` should be enough. That's why you usually have to call `jest.dontMock` in the first place.

You can find more information here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/automatic-mocking.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. However, I don't want Jest to provide an automatic mock because the Jest automatic mock functions don't return anything. Which would make my test fail as it's expecting a string to be translated and returned. The Manual mocking on the jest docs should be what I need as I want a Mocked version of my object that returns exactly what I tell it to.

Comment: How about trying to stick with the automatic mocking and configure the mock in the test? Something like `var i18n = require('i18n'); i18n.t.mockReturnValue('My return string')

Comment: Hi, I tried requiring the thing and mocking the value, but in the actual implementation (inside ChatApp) when t is called it is still returning undefined, so the mock isn't working. The i18n object in the test is mocked correctly but this isn't the i18n object used in the ChatApp code.

Comment: Note that as of 2016, jest no longer does automatic mocking by default: https://web.archive.org/web/20171011061608/https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/09/01/jest-15.html - you can re-enable it per https://web.archive.org/web/20171011043302/https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#automock-boolean

Answer (score 0):

What [mattykuzyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073211/mattykuzyk) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29805544/3340229) did not work at all for me :(

However, what I found out seemed to be the problem for me was the setup of jest: I used `moduleNameMapper` in the beginning, and for some reason these are never mocked...

So for me the first step was to instead move my module name mapped folder to the `moduleDirectories` to get anything to work.

After that, I could simply add a `__mocks__` file adjacent to the actual implementation (in my case `utils/translation.js` and `utils/__mocks__/translation.js`).
As my `translations.js` default exports a translation function, I also default exported my mock. The entire `__mocks__/translations.js` is super simply and looks like this:

```js
export default jest.fn((key, unwrap = false) => (
    unwrap && `${key}-unwrapped` || `${key}-wrapped`
))
```

Although I haven't tested it, adding a `__setReturnString` should be easy enough, for me it was sufficient to actually return my translation key. Hope this helps!